# How to read figure without any symbol?

Tags: c#

How to read figure without any symbol??
example -8759.328 and 8569.659"

output should be 8759.32 and 8569.65 in double

```
 var debit = txtDebit.Text.Split('-');
 oBankPages.DebitAmount = Convert.ToDouble(debit);
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand, you have two strings,

```
var numberStringOne = "-8759.328";
var numberStringTwo = "8569.659";
```

If you want to treat these strings like `decimal`s, first you must **parse** them.

```
var numberOne = decimal.Parse("-8759.328");
var numberTwo = decimal.Parse("8569.659");
```

Next, you could get the value ignoring the **sign**, by using [`Math.Abs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.parse.aspx), Abs. being an abbreviation of Absolute.

```
var numberOne = Math.Abs(numberOne);
```

Then you convert the number back to a rounded string using the appropriate [format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx).

```
var formattedNumberOne = numberOne.ToString("D2");
```

or perhaps

```
Console.WriteLine("{0:D2}", numberTwo);
```

so, all on one line.

```
var formattedNumberOne = Math.Abs(decimal.Parse("-8759.328")).ToString("D2");
```

Answer (score 1):

Formatting can be done only with strings integral and floating point types doesn't have any formatting by thier own

```
var res = Math.Abs(-8759.328).ToString("f2");
```

If at all you need the result as `Double` you can `Round` the result

```
var res = Math.Round(Math.Abs(-8759.328), 2);
```

Note: above calls `Math.Round` so result will be rounded rather than formatted. In other words you may get result as `8759.33` instead of `8759.32`

Comment: how about 8569.659"? also same?

Comment: system can't run on that line straight away run another line

Answer (score 0):

```
 oBankPages.DebitAmount = Math.Abs(Convert.ToDouble(txtDebit.Text));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
string debit = Regex.Replace(txtDebit.Text, "[^0-9^.]+", "");
oBankPages.DebitAmount = Math.Abs(Convert.ToDouble(debit)).ToString("f");
```

Answer (score 0):

Beware that fractions like these cannot be accurately represented in floating point.You can simply solve it out in your case.

```
double value = Math.Truncate(100 * Math.Abs(-8759.328)) / 100;
```

**OUTPUT** : 8759.32

Answer (score 0):

Use `decimal` instead of double. Your data is related to money. Even one cent off is significant. You cannot afford to use floats or doubles, as they are lossy data types that remember only the "beginning" of the number and forget the ending. `decimal` is designed to be precise. If you ever work for financial sector, remember: no floats, no doubles. Of course unless some high-accountant orders tells you they level it up somehow and it's safe due to their creativity..

Read about [Salami Attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salami_slicing)